# Cannot add Blocktrail SDK as a dependency in Composer

Tags: php, sdk, composer-php, php-ini

When trying to add/install Blocktrail SDK as dependency for Composer. It shows
an error like this: [Requested PHP extension GMP is missing from your system. (Link to screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yrBJY.jpg)

I've tried enabling the extension GMP in my cpanel using php.ini. But even if it was enabled it still shows the same error which is very confusing. I already tried communicating this with my hosting provider but they dont know what to do.

Note: I am using PUTTY for installations.

[Blocktrail SDK installation instructions](https://github.com/blocktrail/blocktrail-sdk-php)

So, is there anyone who ever encountered this kind of error? Or is there any alternative to installing the blocktrail-sdk but still using Composer?

Comment: the error seems explicative. you need to install the PHP php5-gmp extension on your server (if you have php5 installed)

Comment: Any ideas how to do this? Isnt gmp just need enabling in php.ini? Thanks in advance

Comment: the fact the hosting does not what to do is scary .... if you are in a webhosting you can not do so much